# How can I get my program to calculate the area of triangles? In Python

Tags: python, cpython

This is my program so far, can someone tell me what I've done wrong or give me a fix for it? It's all in python and I'd really appreciate an answer. The error message pops up saying "Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'".

```
height = input("What is the height of the triangle? ")
width = input("What is the width of the triangle? ")

area = width * height /2

print("The area of the triangle would be {0:f} ".format(area))
```

Comment: `try converting to int `

Comment: What do you mean by converting to int?

Comment: Converting it to float would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your values to the `float` data type:

```
height = float(input("What is the height of the triangle? "))
width = float(input("What is the width of the triangle? "))

area = width * height /2

print("The area of the triangle would be {0:f} ".format(area))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Emil. :)

Comment: This seems to of worked now that I've tried it. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `input` to get your number, but the type returned from `input` method is string. Convert it to int and it will work.

Example:

```
area = int(width) * int(height) /2
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually the input you are using height = input("What is the height of the triangle? ") is just not integer, here is what you can fix

```
height = eval(raw_input("What is the height of the triangle? "))
width = eval(raw_input("What is the width of the triangle?"))
area = width * height /2
print("The area of the triangle would be {0:f} ".format(area))
```

Comment: raw_input was the Python 2 name for input, and eval is dangerous (as was input in Python 2). Given the type specifier :f, the appropriate types would be float or decimal.Decimal.

Comment: This is a dangerous practice. `eval`  will accept any Python code. It might work fine in a toy example like this but teaching it as a general solution may lead to easily cracked code in, for example, a web application.

Comment: Guessing I wont be using that solution then?